# So many tomcat http-worker threads are blocked especially: org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.register

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, performance-testing

**Environment:**
Apache-tomcat-7.0.53,
CentOS release 6.6 (Final),
Java 1.8,
Mongo 2.6

**Design of our App**

We have most of the calls handled with normal servlets(traditional synchronous ones). We do have a 2 asynchronous servlets(servlet 3.0) which delegate their work to ThreadPoolExecutors(threads named http-async-workers).

**Problem:**
We have a database heavy application, but it was performing quite well until 3500ccu.
But when we ramped up the CCU to 7000CCU, to measure the scalability factor, we have a lot waiting at  the following method `org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.register`

This is the profiler snapshot:
[image]

This is the blocked threads view:
[image]

This is the how the threads look like(most of the them are blocked)
[image]

**Query**

Why is *org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.register* blocked than the database calls?
Is it just a symptom of the db issues or the problem itself.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I did a bit of digging. `register(AbstractProcessor<S> processor)` (source [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProtocol.java)) is mostly `synchronized` so that could explain the blocked threads. The profiler snaphot shows this as part of `createProcessor` and that could mean that the `processorCache` parameter (documented [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)) has impact. Try setting this parameter to `-1` (unlimited) or `400` (default is `200`).