# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat Thread Pool Creation Overhead

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat, threadpool

I am wondering if anyone has information on the performance overhead of adding more threads to a tomcat thread pool?

We have been seeing issues with an app of ours and everything points to an issue with tomcat adding more threads to the thread pool.Is this true? Does adding more threads to the thread pool cause a slowdown in response time?

We are running a Java REST API using Spring Boot and its embedded tomcat. If our problems are indeed caused by tomcat adding more threads to the pool, is there a way to set a minimum in Spring? According to this thread MinSpareThreads does not exist anymore. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3753

If there isn't a way to increase the number of minimum threads with Spring Embedded Tomcat, what are other tools that you use for thread pools?

[image: Thread Increase and Response Time Increase]

**Edit:**
I have attached a thread profile. The profile is not of the time in question but later.

[image: Thread Profile]

Comment: You saw the suggestion of TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory ?

Comment: @Marged I did not see it. I know of the container factory but from what I can tell it just provides a little more control over using application.properties.

Comment: It could also be related to some (synchronized) cache mechanism no longer working properly, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29035095/3080094) and my comment with the answer about `processorCache`. Try profiling to see where (and why) threads are waiting.

Comment: @vanOekel I have updated the question with a thread profile. I am not very versed in reading them however.

Comment: By the lack of answers I assume no one has ever measured performance of adding more threads to a threadpool and if that is the actual cause of the slow response time.

Answer (score 0):

We are now able to add the both edges of configuration:

> wilkinsona commented Apr 19, 2016 ->
>   **maxThreads** has always been configurable. **minSpareThreads** can now be configured too (see 34eb369)

[Add configuration option for maxSpareThreads - (Old bug, finally fixed)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3753)